# Gotomeeting on Fedora - crashes often when I start sharing the screen

Tags: fedora

```
Chrome: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
$ uname -a                                          
4.9.9-200.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 9 17:28:13 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ java -version 
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b14, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using wayland?

Comment: That's correct - wayland is used

Comment: give it a try without wayland.